# C# UWP Capture Video/Audio from DirectShow source filters dll(s)

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, speech-recognition, mediacapture

I am trying to capture audio by using C# `Windows.Media.Capture` which is for UWP (I assume).
I tried listing all devices with `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.All);`, to use the device ID in `MediaCaptureInitializationSettings`, but I am unable to find the virtual devices (DirectShow source filters), meaning that it only lists the devices which are physically connected to the system.
I am using UWP for `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition`, and I can't find any way to make it recognize audio files or byte streams, so I am trying to make it use a virtual source filter dll as an audio input device.

So, is there any way with which I can initialize `MediaCapture` that records the virtual filter or make windows think that it's (virtual filter) a connected device?
I am using `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition` as it's only free and works best (I have tried other free libraries).

What I want to avoid doing is downloading a third-party program that requires installation.
I would like to know any alternatives with which I can change the default source for `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition`.

Comment: Can you see the virtual device in the Device Manager? If the virtual device is listed in the Device Manager, then the `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync` should be able to find it. If not, then UWP can't find it.

Comment: No, I was not able to find it in Device Manager. So is there any way I can make it list there? Or any alternative to `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync`?

Comment: I have to say no. There is no way to do that.